# show dates from current day till the end of the week

Tags: angularjs, laravel

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Pick up
        <span class="pull-right" ng-value="month">{{month.m}} - {{month.y}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <label class="control-label selectShiftLable">Select Shift For Each Date</label>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <span style="color:green;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>&nbsp Accepted Shifts &nbsp
            <span style="color:orange;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp Under Review &nbsp
            <span style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></span>&nbsp Modified Shifts &nbsp
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value)  in pickupdata">
            <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon" style=" font-size:13px;width: 47%;" ng-value="daysArray">{{($index+1)}}-{{daysArray[$index]}}
                        <a href="#" id="show-option" title="Shift was approved by Team Lead">
                            <span ng-if="acceptedpickupdata[$index+1]" style="color:green;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="show-option" title="Shift is under Review by Team Lead">
                            <span ng-if="underreviewpickupdata[$index+1]" style="color:orange;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="show-option" title="Shift has been modified by the Team Lead">
                            <span ng-if="modifiedpickupdata[$index+1]" style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control " style="font-size:10px;display: inline;padding:0px" ng-options="shift.code as shift.name for shift in shiftList"
                        ng-model="pickupdata[$index+1]" ng-disabled="blockedPickupList[$index+1]">
                        <option value="">
                            Select Shift
                        </option>
                    </select>

                    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Ui looks like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfM75.png

Now assume that i have two radio buttons weekly and monthly when user press on weekly then i have to show only the days from current day till sunday and if its monthly then it will look as it is now in the ui i.e all the days from current day till the end of the month 
actually i am new to angular !

Comment: Can you show us your efforts ? as in what have u tried till now ? Better create a plunkr and share the url to get a working solution

Comment: @ShashankVivek https://stackblitz.io is better for Angular-related questions

Comment: Since you are new to angular, why are you using angular 1? Anyway, you can do that with filters without touching you original data

Comment: @trichetriche I agree, but plunkr is also good for `angularjs` but bad for `angular`

Comment: @ShashankVivek my bad, the question is mistagged !